# Android Maps V2 - Move a circle smoothly

Tags: android, google-maps

I currently have a mapfragment using Google Maps API V2 for Android in my application.

On this map, I drew a circle like this:

```
/* CIRCLE */
CircleOptions circleOptions = new CircleOptions()
    .center(new LatLng(50,4))
    .radius(10000);
    circle = mMap.addCircle(circleOptions);
    circle.setFillColor(0x4496AA39);
    circle.setStrokeColor(0xDD96AA39);
```

This circle move and is resized periodically (based on the GPS activity), like this:

```
circle.setRadius(newRadius);
circle.setCenter(newCenter);
```

The problem is that when the circle is either resized or moved, the circle is transparent for some frames, and is filled after some milliseconds.

I also tried to clear the map and readd the circle, but the result is the same:

```
mMap.clear();
CircleOptions circleOptions = new CircleOptions()
.center(newCenter)
.radius(newRadius);
circle = mMap.addCircle(circleOptions);
circle.setFillColor(0x4496AA39);
circle.setStrokeColor(0xDD96AA39);
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: I have the same problem with fast updating Circle radius and center. Take a look http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=5707&thanks=5707&ts=1376049494